# GoogleMap MarkerClusterer Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am trying to convert my GoogleMap to use MarkerClusterer. I have simplified everything down so that once my map is created, I can add a MarkerClusterer with my markers. In this case I am trying to make only one marker.

```
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(20,20),
  map:map
  });
  console.log("about to make markerCluster")
  markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map,[]);
  console.log("made markerCluster")
  console.log("trying to add marker")
  markerCluster.addMarker(marker)
  console.log("added marker")
```

Here I get to "trying to add marker" and no further. The error messsage given in Chrome Javascript Console is:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function markerclusterer.js:155

isMarkerInViewport_ markerclusterer.js:155

MarkerClusterer.addMarker markerclusterer.js:183
(anonymous function)

...

Any ideas?

Comment: note: this is lines 154-156 in markerclusterer.js, and the marker is added when I comment out the return statement. This will almost certainly harm me in the long run though: 

  function isMarkerInViewport_(marker) {                                       
    return map_.getBounds().containsLatLng(marker.getLatLng());
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my own issue: was using version 1.0 and needed to be using issue 2.1 >.< thank you to anyone who looked into this